# Isometry of quadratic space

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, semigroups

> Every element of $K$ is a square if and only if every 2-dimensional form over $K$ is isotropic. In fact, if $\langle -1, d \rangle$ is isotropic, then $\langle - 1,d \rangle \cong \langle -1, 1\rangle$ and d is a square.

I know that if every element of $K$ is square  Then two regular quadratic spaces over
K are isometric if and only if they have the same dimension hence $\langle- 1,d\rangle \cong \langle-1, 1\rangle$  and d is square since it is discriminant of quadratic space which is define as $(-1)^n$ det($\phi$) where $\dim(\phi)=2n$ or $\dim(\phi)=2n+1$.

How to prove the above cases?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.